# What does the ==~ operator do?

Tags: ruby, regex, operators

What does the `==~` operator do as in the following?

```
['a','b','c'].join ==~ /b/
# =>false
```

I tried a few different arrays and strings and never received a syntax error, but `==~` seems to be a regex comparison operator that always returns `false`.

Comment: I will not accept my answer until others have had a chance to write a better one. I am curious as to why ~/b/ is nil instead of a syntax error or meaningful answer and is this treated as "== ~" and not "= =~".

Comment: `= =~` would not make sense.

Comment: @sawa It would trigger a syntax which would.

Comment: @Sqeaky, It chooses `== ~` because the `~` operator have precedence over the `==` and `=~` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `==~` is actually `==` and `~` but a unary `~` has a different meaning for a regex that you think it does. From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-7E):

> **~ rxp → integer or nil**
>
> Match—Matches *rxp* against the contents of `$_`. Equivalent to `rxp =~ $_`.
>
> ```
> $_ = "input data"
> ~ /at/   #=> 7
> ```

Generally you'd use `~regex` in a command line one liner that uses one of [the switches](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html#UA) that wraps your Ruby in an implicit loop and sets `$_`.

Consider this simple example and you'll see what's going on:

```
>> $_ = 'pancakes'
=> "pancakes"
>> ~/pancakes/
=> 0
>> 0 ==~ /pancakes/
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually two different operators `==` and `~`. `~` is a bitwise `not` or bitwise complement operator. When used against a regular expression it always evaluates to nil. I think this is because regular expressions do not have a meaningful bitwise pattern.

```
>~/b/
=> nil
```

When you compare nil to anything (except nil) you get false.

```
>a=60
=> 60
> ~a
=> -61
```

If you have a variable `a` and it is storing 60 as a Fixnum, on x86 its actually storing `00111100`. In this case `~a` returns the value represented by `11000011`, -61.